# Pycharm Issue when sharing project on Github: only the .idea directory files show up in the changelog

Tags: github, version-control, pycharm

I wanted to tidy up a Pycharm project where I've been solving bioinformatics problems from rosalind.info in order to upload the project to Github. The way the project directory is structured is as follows:

Project_Directory
../.idea
../Data_files
../venv

All of my .py scripts plus some output .csv and .txt files are located in Project_Directory.

I tried to share the entire project to my Github account. However, the only files that appear in the Commit window are some .xml files within the .idea directory.

How can I undo the process to start from scratch, and how can I make it so that I'm able to upload the code I've written, which is contained in the various .py files?

I've tried both removing the project's directory from the 'Settings>Version control' window of Pycharm, as well as deleting the created repository in my Github profile. However, whenever I try to start the process of sharing the project on github, the repository is created again, and the Commit window continues to only show files from the .idea directory.